# Active Scaffold: how to filter the query

Tags: search, controller, ruby-on-rails-3.2, parameters, activescaffold

I need to filter my query in active scaffold 3.2.19 to display only customers that have the field "end_date" >= current date or "end_date" is null.
I already tried to use conditions_for_collection, but if my user needs to filter the costumers that have end_date is not null or <= current date he will can't, so I tried to use field_search.default_params but i can't understand how to use.

Any ideas???

thanks